# Import a .atomsvc file from Reporting Services

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssis

I'm fairly sure I'm missing something really obvious here so hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

A client of ours has spun up a standard public facing SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services webpage. It shows a few columns of data, based on a couple of drop down filters. It has the standard `export to...` options (Excel, PDF and so on). It also had a button that downloads an `atomsvc` file which I understand is for importing the data into `Excel` via `PowerPivot`.

Is it possible to import the data this file links to into `SQL Server` in a fairly straightforward way (T-SQL, linked data source, SSIS ect) or should I just import the Atom data the file links to as I would any other XML?

I can't find much online that doesn't talk about `PowerPivot` in relation to these atom feeds but it seems to me that, as a standard feature of `SQL Server`reporting services, it should be easily importable into `SQL server`.

Alternatively am I completely missing a much easy way to import data from an HTTP reporting services page? Obviously I don't have console level access to the server as it's a public facing webpage.

Answer (score 6):

So I've done a bit of digging and learned about [URL Access (SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms153586.aspx) for SQL Server Reporting Services.

The .atomsvc file contains a link to the raw data feed. This can be easily tweaked quite extensively. In particular there is a "Format" specifier available which can be used to export as normal XML / CSV / whatever. For example:

```
http://myrshost/ReportServer?/myreport&rs:Format=XML

http://myrshost/ReportServer?/myreport&rs:Format=CSV
```

I hope this helps someone. I was as I suspected missing something "obvious" but it was knowing what to Google that tripped me up.

I still can't help thinking that there should be an easy way to just download the .atomsvc file and open it with SQL Management Studio or SSIS rather than PowerPivot but XML / CSV is fairly straight forward o deal with.